# Pivot item show next Pivot Item content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivotitem

I have two pivot Items, I want to show a part of second pivot item content while I am on first pivot Item. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.pivotitem%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) links are pivot and pivotItem class links, I couldn't find anything helpful.
Example Apps: ESPN and XBOX app in windows store has this type of behaviours.

Comment: What you are looking for is a Panorama control for Windows Phone 8 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941104(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Panorama is now hub control? Am I right ?

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developerswhat-controls-are-new-2/

Comment: I actually used Hub after that, but the problem is that it shows next items but It doesn't navigate like pivot items. Mean you can stop them at the mid of both items.

Comment: For Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight App) & Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight App), we have Panorama Control : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202885(v=vs.105).aspx & for Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML App), we have Hub Control : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn596112.aspx

Comment: So can I change HUB's navigation like a PIVOT Control?